# Piped observable not emitting when source emits

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
public lotId$ = new Subject<number>();

@Input() public set lotId(value: number) {
    this.lotId$.next(value);
};

public results$ = this.lotId$.asObservable().pipe(
    skipWhile(lotId => !lotId),
    switchMap(lotId => this.logicService.getMappedTakeOffTasksForLot(lotId)),
    tap(console.log)
);
```

In the code above, `results$` does not emit every time `lotId$` emits. Anyone know why? the code runs over `results$` once when the component is created and then never again.

EDIT: The source emits 58.

EDIT: It works when I change from `Subject` to `BehaviorSubject`. Why? I wish I tried that sooner.

Comment: When new value coming to input then at that time restult$ is not yet ready to serve you value, BehaviorSubject is working because of you have to pass initial value to behaviorSubject when you create it, so, before input() gets called you already pass value to result$ and stream is ready to listen value .

Comment: @GRD ahhhh nice. I thought the only difference was you can get the synchronous value from a BehaviorSubject. But the initial value is also a key reason to use! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> results$ does not emit every time lotId$ emits.

Subscriptions to `results$` that occur before `lotId$` emits, will receive those values.  To put it another way, late subscribers don't receive prior values (*by "late subscriber" I mean subscription after some emissions have occurred*).

Assuming you are using `async` pipe in your template, the subscription of `results$` doesn't happen until after the view has been initialized, but the @Input() setters are called before that happens.

You will find that if you subscribe in the constructor (*just for experimentation*), the derived `results$` will in fact emit the initial values.

So, it should be clear why changing to [`BehaviorSubject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) works; Upon subscription, it emits the latest previous value to new subscribers.

However, a `BehaviorSubject` requires a default value (*which will of course be emitted to new subscribers*). It may not always be appropriate to emit a default value, so you could instead use [`ReplaySubject(1)`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/replaysubject), which will also emit previous value to new subscribers, but doesn't require a default value.

The image below shows the output received by the template based on the type of subject that is used (`Subject` / `ReplaySubject` / `BehaviorSubject`):

[image: compare behavior of different subject types]

If a component has an optional `@Input()`, I use `BehaviorSubject` since a default value is needed.  If the input is required I use `ReplaySubject(1)`, so my logic is not executed unless the consumer provides the input.

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-70409381?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts) where you can see the order of the Angular lifecycle hooks and when the subscriptions occur.